# Touchscreen Windows 7 WPF

Tags: wpf, windows-7, touchscreen

I have an app which I need to make accessible for Windows Touch.  It is not a **multi**-touch application.  I've looked at Microsoft's [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872774.aspx) for touch applications which is interesting.  There is one thing I am not clear on though, that is text input.

I would like a keyboard to appear when I click in a TextBox field.  Is there a way to use the built-in on screen keyboard for this?

The first monitor I tested with was a Wacom.  It is an older unit that uses a pen.  It had some software that pulled up an on screen keyboard whenever I clicked in any text field (in any application).  It was very handy.  I thought this feature was using built-in Windows Tablet software because it didn't look like it came from a third party.  A newer monitor I just purchased (Elo) does not have this feature though.

Comment: Looks like I've found the problem.  The general purpose driver for the monitor wasn't installing it as a Tablet PC monitor.  The Windows 7 only driver will provide a Tablet PC control panel settings.  Now a keyboard shows up whenever I click in a TextBox field.  The Windows XP compatible driver must have been using a legacy sub-system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question so it won't show up as unanswered any longer...  From my comment above:

> Looks like I've found the problem. The general purpose driver for the monitor wasn't installing it as a Tablet PC monitor. The Windows 7 only driver will provide a Tablet PC control panel settings. Now a keyboard shows up whenever I click in a TextBox field. The Windows XP compatible driver must have been using a legacy sub-system...